# Is there something in MySQL like IN but which uses AND instead of OR?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a SQL statement to retrieve records where it key (or any column) is in a associate table, for example:

```
documentId termId
4             1
4             2
3             3
5             1
```

This:

```
SELECT documentId 
  FROM table 
 WHERE termId IN (1,2,3)
```

...will retrieve any `documentid` value where the `termid` value is 1 **or** 2 **or** 3.

Is there something like this but return `documentid` values where the `termid` values are 1 **and** 2 **and** 3? Like an IN but with AND.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no straight forward functionality, but there are two options:

### Using GROUP BY/HAVING

---

```
  SELECT t.documentid
    FROM TABLE t
   WHERE t.termid IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY t.documentid
  HAVING COUNT(DISINCT t.termid) = 3
```

The caveat is that you have to use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT` because duplicates of termid being 2 for the same documentid would be a false positive.  And the COUNT has to equal the number of termid values in the IN clause.

### Using JOINs

---

```
SELECT t.documentid
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN TABLE x ON x.termid = t.termid
              AND x.termid = 1
  JOIN TABLE y ON y.termid = t.termid
              AND y.termid = 2
  JOIN TABLE z ON z.termid = t.termid
              AND z.termid = 3
```

But this one can be a pain for handling criteria that changes a lot.

Comment: For those wondering about the performance difference between these two methods, have a [look at this answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31102803/4248167) In summary, the join method puts less strain on the database.