# Rails: Using will_paginate with a complex association find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I'm encountering a problem with will_paginate while doing a complex find.

```
:photo  has_many   :tags,   :through => :tagships
:item   has_many   :photos
:photo  belongs_to :item


@photos = @item.photos.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                :per_page => 200,
                                :conditions => [ 'tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids],
                                :order => 'created_at DESC',
                                :joins => :tags,
                                :group => "photos.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = #{tag_count}"
```

I want to fetch all the photos who have all the tags in the tag_ids array. MySQL's IN usually does "or" searches, but I need "and". I found how to modify IN to mimic "and" behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860374/is-there-something-in-mysql-like-in-but-which-uses-and-instead-of-or) and it works fine when using model.find(), also works as long as the number of records fetched is lower than my :per_page count. But if it has to paginated, the SQL that is generated is similar to:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all, photos.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 1 AS photos_id_having_count_distinct_tags_id_1 FROM `photos`(...)
```

which doesn't work. Other have seen this bug and were able to move their count() out of the query, but I don't think that's possible in my case.

Is there a better way to do this search that might work with will_paginate? If its the only way to do this, I guess I should look into another pagination plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

FYI, here's what I finally found to fix this:

```
@photos = WillPaginate::Collection.create(current_page, per_page) do |pager|
    result = @item.photos.find :all, :conditions => [ 'tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids] ,:order => 'created_at DESC', :joins => :tags, :group => "photos.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = #{@tags.count}", :limit => pager.per_page, :offset => pager.offset
    pager.replace(result)

    unless pager.total_entries
      pager.total_entries = @item.photos.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids] ,:order => 'created_at DESC', :joins => :tags, :group => "photos.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = #{@tags.count}").count
    end
  end
```

You have to manually construct the paginated set using the page number as an offset and using the tags to make a join query. Kinda clunky.

Answer (score 1):

My first stab at this (sorry don't have time to test it right now... will update if I do) would be something like the following (added the :select and changed the :group):

```
@photos = @item.photos.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                :per_page => 200,
                                :select => "photos.*, COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) AS tag_count",
                                :conditions => [ 'tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids ],
                                :order => 'created_at DESC',
                                :joins => :tags,
                                :group => "photos.id HAVING tag_count = #{tag_count}"
```