# sort_by or order by row from an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to sort an index of submissions.

Each submission `has_one :score` and score `belongs_to :submission` submission `belongs_to :contest` and contest `has_many :submissions`

the row I want to sort by is `submission.score.subtotal` in submissions>index

I have tried this:

```
 @submissions = submission.find(:all, :include => :score).sort_by { |s| s.scores.sub_total }.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

I have assigned scores to all the submissions in contest one, but when I try to bring up submissions>index for contest one (assigned through params), I'm getting an error:

```
NoMethodError at /submissions
undefined method `sub_total' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm pretty sure I need to check for nil somewhere, but I'm missing where that would be.

More information:

```
def index
  contest_id = params[:contest_id]
  @contest = Contest.find(contest_id)
  submission = Submission.where(:contest_id => params[:contest_id])
  if params[:search].blank?
   @submissions = submission.find(:all, :include => :score).sort_by { |s| s.score.sub_total }.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  else 
   @submissions = submission.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
   @search = params[:search] 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you need:

```
@submissions = Submission.find(:all, :joins => :score, :order => 'scores.sub_total DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

I hope this helped you

Comment: Getting an error on that one: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /submissions
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "score"
LINE 1: ...id" WHERE "submissions"."contest_id" = 1 ORDER BY score.subt...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "scores"."submission_id" = "submissions"."id" WHERE "submissions"."contest_id" = 1 ORDER BY score.subtotal DESC` I added the controller information in the question because there's a contest.id involved that may throw the query off

Comment: Sorry my bad, i edited my answer. It should be ":order => 'scores.sub_total'"

Comment: Okay, that works, except it will not paginate: `NoMethodError at /submissions
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007fbaa085a5b8>`

Comment: Well yes paginate don't accept complex select. You should have a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868484/rails-using-will-paginate-with-a-complex-association-find

Comment: I had to add `require 'will_paginate/array'` to the gemfile to make it work. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Scratch that, I had to create an initializer and then drop in `require 'will_paginate/array'` It did not belong in the gemfile, obvious mistake. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array