# select rows with a set of values (in multiple rows in Conjunction [And]) in sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table like:

````````````````````
id............value
```````````````````
A............1
A............2
A............3
B............1
````````````````````

and so on.

so, If I want to select rows with Value either 1 OR 2 OR 3, I do this:

```
select id From table where value in (1,2,3)
```

But, what I want to do is, select id with AND instead of OR. I want it like

so If I want to select rows where Id has value 1, 2 AND 3, (in this case, resultant = A), how do I select that?

Thanks!
(I tried to do it myself, no luck, I tried to search on google, I realized I dint even know how to phrase the question! so if the question here doesnt agree with my actual doubt, feel free to change it)

Comment: Nearly identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860374/is-there-something-in-mysql-like-in-but-which-uses-and-instead-of-or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select id 
from MyTable
where value in (1, 2, 3) 
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 3
```

Comment: the value will be passed from codebehind. its not a constant, but I Get the idea... i guess i will split the CSV values and count(*) it and place that variable instead of 3, would that work?

Comment: @iamserious: that will work, as long as the number for 3 matches the number of distinct values - make sure your value passed from codebehind has no duplicates in it.

Comment: I simplified the case here, but my querry was way more complicated.. and finally after trial-error method, i got it to work, but, all thanks to you, your querry works flawlessly, without any change! cheers! thanks a ton! you just saved me a lot of while loop debugging and coding!

Comment: @iamserious: np - keep naming your tables MyTable and most queries on SO will work ;)

Comment: hahaha!! thanks for the tip, btw my table name is really not "table" ! I just renamed it here!! but i like your sense of humour! (now that my problem is solved!!)